# Using HBase / Hadoop / Storm

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, apache-pig, bigdata

I receive an input file which has 200 MM of records. The records are just a keys.
For each record from this file (which i'll call SAMPLE_FILE), i need to retrieve all records from a database (which i'll call EVENT_DATABASE ) that match key . The EVENT_DATABASE can have billions of records.

For example:

```
SAMPLE_FILE
1234
2345
3456


EVENT_DATABASE
2345 - content C - 1
1234 - content A - 3
1234 - content B - 5
4567 - content D - 7
1234 - content K - 7
1234 - content J - 2
```

So the system will iterate through each record from SAMPLE_RECORD and get all EVENTS which has the same key. For example, getting 1234 and query the EVENT_DATABASE will retrieve:

```
1234 - content A - 3
1234 - content B - 5
1234 - content K - 7
1234 - content J - 2
```

Then i will execute some calculations using the result set. For example, count, sum, mean

```
F1 = 4 (count)
F2 = 17 (sum(3+5+7+2))
```

I will approach the problem storing the EVENT_DATABASE using HBASE. Then i will run a map-reduce job, and in the map phase i will query the HBase, get he events and execute the calculations. 
The process can be in batch. It is not necessary to be real time.

Does anyone suggests another architecture? Do i really need a map reduce job? Can i use another approach?

Answer (score 0):

I personally solved this kind of problem using MapReduce, HDFS & HBase for batch analysis. Your approach seems to be good for implementing your use-case I am guessing you are going to store the calculations back into HBase.

Storm could also be used to implement the same usecase, but Storm really shines with streaming data & near real time processing rather than data at rest.

Comment: I will try to use the EVENT_DATABASE as a hadoop MAP FILE.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to query Hbase for every single event. According to me this would be a better approach.

1. Create an external table in hive using your input file.
2. Create an external table in hive for your hbase table using Hive Hbase Integration (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration)
3. Do a join on both the tables and get the retrieve the results.

Your approach would have been good if you were only querying for a subset of your input file but since you are querying hbase for all recrods (20M), using a join would be more efficient.

Comment: Do you know if hbase index will be used? If not i dont see advantages in this approach.

Comment: No hbase index won't be used here....the advantage here would be to use Hive which does well in joining large tables. May be you can try both the approaches and compare the execution time.